# PMML Can you remove special characters in strings?

Tags: pmml

Is there a way to remove special characters in a pmml string?  Something like below but I have added a made up function call "removeSpecialCharacters".

```
<DerivedField name="stringmatch" datatype="string" optype="categorical">
     <Apply function="if">
          <Apply function="equal">
                <Apply function="removeSpecialCharacters">
                     <FieldRef="string1"/>
                </Apply>
                <Apply function="removeSpecialCharacters">
                     <FieldRef="string2"/>
                </Apply>
          </Apply>
     <Constant>1</Constant>
     <Constant>0</Constant>
     </Apply>
<DerivedField/>
```

This results in one if matching and zero if no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove special characters using the built-in PMML [replace](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/BuiltinFunctions.html#replace) function - simply specify an empty string as the replacement value.